# I need to sort my random numbers generated and add them to the second editText2

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.sai.generatinrandomnumbers;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
```

// I need to sort my random numbers generated and add them to the second editText2 in my application i tried using collections but i couldn't figure it out plz help me and I'm attaching my code below.should i use a arraylist again??

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText, editText2;
    Button button, button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setEnabled(false);

        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText2.setEnabled(false);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random r = new Random();
                ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    int answer = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
                    num.add(answer);
                    editText.setText(String.valueOf(num));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read all the Integers into your data structure and then print them back sorted to a 2nd EditText Widget. Alright, let's do something like this:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random r = new Random();
            ArrayList<Integer> num = getRandomNums(6);
            editText.setText(getStringNum(num));

            Collections.sort(num);
            editText2.setText(getStringNum(num));
    });



private List<Integer> getRandomNums(final int theNumDigits) {
    Random r = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < theNumDigits; i++) {
        int answer = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        num.add(answer);
        }

     return num;
 }

 private String getStringNum(final List<Integer> theNumbers) {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for (int i = 0; i < theNumbers.size(); i++) {
           sb.append(num.get(i));
         }

        String toReturn = sb.toString();
        sb.setLength(0);
        return toReturn;

 }
```

I reformatted the code for you to help you understand exactly what is going on. You're getting all the randomly generated numbers and adding them to an ArrayList. Then creating a String using a StringBuilder ***You were overwriting your previously set value in the EditText each time your loop iterated***

Then you call Collections.sort() and do the whole thing over again.